# Dart, ValueListenableBuilder is giving "Bad State: No element" error

Tags: dart, two-factor-authentication, flutter-hive

I dont know why it is not working. My ValueListenableBulder is empty and I dont know why. I am new in coding and new in dart.
I get an "Bad State: No element" error

It would make me happy if i just get an output if I have something in my list and if not it should print nothing

I dont know why my ListView.builder has nothing in it, and I also do not know how to write a fallback for that problem.

I hope you understand my problem. If you need more information so please just leave a comment on this.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const Icon(
          MyFlutterApp.teckproLog,
          size: 50,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("Authenticator"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => Hive.box(HiveBoxes.otpStrings.name)
                  .add("otpauth://totp/ASFA?secret=ASDD"),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add))
        ],
      ),
      body: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: Hive.box(HiveBoxes.otpStrings.name).listenable(),
          builder: (context, box, _) {
            List<OtpModel> otpObjects = box.values
                .map((otpString) => OtpModel.fromUri(otpString))
                .toList();

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: otpObjects.reversed.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  String code = OTP.generateTOTPCodeString(
                      otpObjects[index].secret,
                      DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                      interval: _animationLength,
                      algorithm: Algorithm.SHA1,
                      isGoogle: true);
```